# jquery $.when - any way to stop .fail from firing early?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

According to the jQuery documentation of $.when, if any of the argument promises fail, then .when WON'T wait, and will immediately fail. It also will NOT cancel the other promises.

**Is there a way to force $.when to actually wait until all its promises have been completed? Alternatively, is there a different method I can/should use?**

Perhaps it is a case of using the wrong tool, but I'm trying to block the UI (loading spinner) while getting data for 2 sections simultaneously. I can handle failure for either/both sections independently. When (and only when) ALL the promises are done (success or failure), then I want to unblock the page.

In the sample code below, "callSvc" is a test method that takes a string "service" identifier, a server-sleep in ms, and an indicator if the web call should fail.

```
callSvc("sync", 0, false)
    .then(function (result) {
        return $.when(
            callSvc("ebill", 4000, false)
                .then(function (a, b, c, d) {
                    debugger;   
                }),
            callSvc("epol", 2000, true)
                .done(function () {
                    // set up epol section with data
                    debugger;
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    // set up epol section for failure
                    debugger;
                })
        ).done(function (ebill, epol) {
            // just here to test ways to stop early-fail
            debugger;
        }).fail(function () {
            // just here to test ways to stop early-fail
            debugger;
        })
    }).fail(function (err) {
        // show message
        debugger;   
    }).always(function () {
        // unblock the screen
        debugger;
    });
```

Comment: We're using jquery 2.1.0

Comment: Have done something similar in node promises.  The way we found around it failing is resolving all promises in the all call (i.e. $.when) and adding a success flag.

Comment: You could possibly chain a `.catch()` on your promises.

Comment: @FissureKing - I'm getting .catch() isn't a function, so, maybe my jquery is too old.

Comment: @emery.noel, it's a method on `Promise`, but now I see that `callSvc` is something else that just happens to have a `then` method.

Comment: @FissureKing - callSvc just returns $.ajax call, so it's a jquery promise ... but my jquery is a bit old.

Answer (score 1):

For both a multi-arg `$.when()` or `Promise.all`, the specification is to fail as soon as any of the calls fail. However, with a small wrapper method, you can turn a failure into a (temporary) success. This is equivalent to calling `catch`, but uses the two-arg `then` call instead:

```
function wrapWithSuccessFlag(promise) {
  return promise.then(
      successfulValue => { return { success: true, value: successfulValue }; },
      failureReason => { return { success: false, reason: failureReason }; });
}

callSvc("sync", 0, false).then(result => {
    return $.when(
        wrapWithSuccessFlag(callSvc("ebill", 4000, false)
            .then(function (a, b, c, d) {
                debugger;   
            })),
        wrapWithSuccessFlag(callSvc("epol", 2000, true)
            .done(function () {
                // set up epol section with data
                debugger;
            })
            .fail(function () {
                // set up epol section for failure
                debugger;
            }))
    ).done(function (ebill, epol) {
        // Determine whether ebill and epol succeeded or failed.
        // You can also throw an error here using ebill or epol's reason,
        // which gets you the error handling you're used to.
    });
```

Comment: Interesting! I will give it a try!

Comment: I tried it a couple of different ways (including copy/paste), but it's not working. I'm hitting epol's fail (as expected), then ebill's "then" ... but I'm never getting into the "done". If I attach an always to "sync", I'm getting into it as soon as the first fail hits.

Comment: @emery.noel It's working for me, with a little adjustment for manual button presses: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/626959/

Comment: I see in your fiddle that you're using $.Deferred objects, which is a little different than the code you posted :) But $.Deferred is the way I'm going to have to go.

Comment: @emery.noel Right, that's one of the manual button press adjustments; your `callSvc` is presumably more self-contained than a button-powered demonstration. Without a self-contained example you provide, this is the best I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it appears the answer is **No**. Instead, I had to manually manage my own promises/deferreds.

Here is the code pattern I ended up using:

```
var callSvc = function (svcName, sleep, shouldFail) {
    return $.ajax{...};
}

callSvc("sync", 0, true)
    .then(function (result) {

        var ebillPromise = $.Deferred();
        var epolPromise = $.Deferred();

        callSvc("ebill", 4000, false)
            .then(function (data) {
                // ebill success
                debugger;
                ebillPromise.resolve();
            }, function () {
                // ebill fail
                debugger;
                ebillPromise.resolve();
            });
        callSvc("epol", 2000, true)
            .then(function (data) {
                // epol success
                debugger;
                epolPromise.resolve();
            }, function () {
                // epol fail
                debugger;
                epolPromise.resolve();
            });

        return $.when(
            ebillPromise,
            epolPromise
        )
    }).fail(function () {
        debugger;
    }).always(function () {
        // unblock the screen
        debugger;
    });
```

This works because my promises are never "rejected", so my $.when() will wait.

But it sure would be nice if we could tell JQuery to wait. Maybe a "$.reallyWait()" function ... ? :)

Thanks to @JeffBowman and @bhmahler for getting me pointed in the right direction!